How to get selected indexes of a QgsAttributeTableView
I have got a subclass of QgsAttributeTableView and I want a list with indexes of all selected rows of the view.
I have already tried
self.view.selectedIndexes()
and
self.view.selectionModel().selectedRows()
Both trials returns an empty list.
I know that there is also self.view.model().layer().selectedFeatures(). This method works and gives me a list of the selected features.
But I want a list with the indexes of the selected rows of the view.
By the way the signal self.view.selectionModel().selectionChanged is also not emited. How can I emit this too?

What if you try the selectedFeatureIds method ?

I have in my application also QTableView's with some method based on a list with the selected row indexes. It would be much easier too use the same methods. Why does the SelectionModel not work (no signal on change is emitted and the list that is returned with self.view.selectionModel().selectedRows()is emty)?

I'll try to ilustrate the situation with my case, constructing dialog for a plugin on QGis.
First, to get the signal is necessary connect the method to table view element in dialog:
    self.dlg.view.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.selectItem)

In my method I'll select some features from specific layer based on multi selections on table view, but here, to answer the question, I'll just append indexes to an array:
    def selectItem(self):
        selrows = self.dlg.view.selectionModel().selectedRows()
        listindex = []
        for item in sorted(selrows):
            listindex.append(item.row())

Hope this helps someone else who is looking for something similar.
